# POST with cURL to a url

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to replace the below form with cURL to automatically post the hidden input types to another url.

```
echo ('<form method="post" action="action-url" class="animate">

<input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="redirect-url">
<input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes">

<button type="submit" value="Enter">Grain Access</button>

</form>');
```

The values are fixed.

```
$_POST['mode_login'] = 'mode_login';
$_POST['redirect'] = 'redirect-url';
$_POST['accept_terms'] = 'yes';
```

So now, how do I post these values using cURL to a url?

What i am trying to achieve is automatically redirect the user, without them having to click anything. And without using JS.

Comment: There are hundreds of guides on how to deal with curl in php. Have you spent even a minute on your own research?

Comment: I have, haven't managed to find anything specific to what I'm looking for hence I am on here...if you know what would be the best way to do this please share @zerkms

Comment: "haven't managed to find anything specific" --- it's fine that you just learn how to do something in general then apply you knowledge for your particular case. Eg: you wasn't taught how to evaluate `42 + 42` in particular, but you know how `+` works so you can add those. Do you see the point? What is so special in your case? You just send a post request to a remote url like any guide explains.

Comment: @zerkms Check the answer, is it anything like that? And will the processing script be able to distinguish if it's been sent from a form or not? Cause it shouldn't be able to.

Comment: "And will the processing script be able to distinguish if it's been sent from a form or not?" --- it only depends on how precise and thoughtful you are. `HTTP` request is just a bunch of headers and a body. It's up to you on how you want it to look like the "real" one. And it's up to the other side about how to check if it's a real browser or not.

Comment: @zerkms I'm a newb. Can I please get some feedback for the answer I posted, cause it doesn't seem to work? And can I please get some tips on how to make sure it will be seen as if it were sent from a form?

Comment: Learn how HTTP works first. Then capture all the headers sent by your browser (using chrome dev tools or fiddler). Then replicate all of them in your code. It will work in most cases (unless you're trying to fool google or facebook)

Comment: I know how html works you don't have to be so condescending. Newb with php. If you're not gonna offer any help, why are you even on here? Certainly you didn't know php outta the womb. @zerkms

Comment: 1. HTTP not HTML 2. Your "help" currently sounds like "do that for me". It's not obvious what is confusing if you really understand HTTP. Just take all headers that your browser sends and send them with curl. What is not clear here for you?

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!empty($_POST['fes-email'])) {

            if (filter_var($_POST['fes-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

 $_POST['mode_login'] = 'mode_login';
        $_POST['redirect'] = 'redirect-url';
        $_POST['accept_terms'] = 'yes';

        $url = "action-url";

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

        curl_exec($ch);
        $result =curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($result);

    }else { echo("EMAIL IS NOT VALID"); }

        }else { echo("EMPTY FIELD"); }
```

Comment: You need to add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);` or there is nothing to post

Comment: @MikeMiller Kept on loading for a minute maybe...and then showed the echoed content. Didn't redirect and post to the url.

Comment: It won't redirect with just the code you have. Its not like the form action attribute the above code will just post the data you need to send something to the browser to tell it to redirect using header like this `header("Location:http://where_you_want_it_to_go.com");`

Comment: No it will post asynchronously so the data will go and then the browser will change location. You would need to put the post data into something you can retrieve it from when the browser moves like a session store or a database. I think you are making this hard for yourself you are probably better off doing this with the hidden form fields and using JavaScript to do the automatic post and redirect

Comment: Or instead of post you can put these params in the query string like `header("location:http://your_URL.com?mode_login=mode_login&redirect=redirect-url&accept_terms=yes")`

Comment: @MikeMiller I was trying to avoid JS. And there is a lag till the page loads and only then the form gets submitted... Is there any other way?

Comment: @MikeMiller  Thats good. Only problem is the processing script is not really controlled by me. Its a hotspot script NoCatSplash. And it will only read a submitted form. Thats why I've been trying to recreate a form post using php and curl.

Comment: Why do you need to redirect the browser? Can you not post the data, handle response and serve up your result in php?

Comment: Also bit of a side point but would really advise using a library- Guzzle is awesome

Comment: I don't need to redirect. I need to post the contents to the hotspot script installed in the router and then once the request from the form gets processed, the processing script redirects to a success page. But the curl method i tried above didn't work. Even though I replicated the way the form posts exactly. @MikeMiller

Comment: Yeah it won't work like that. Put `$result =curl_exec($ch);` and var_dump $result. Hopefully you can get the redirect location back and use it using php header. Curl won't redirect like a form action will. So to be clear if you want the browser to change location after posting from php you definitely do need to redirect

Comment: @MikeMiller Check the answer above...like that?

Comment: No sorry just do `var_dump($result);` and see what you are getting back in response to the http request that curl is making. It will print contents out hopefully somewhere in there is the location to send the browser

Comment: Nothing it just keeps loading